# How to complete Cayley table in order to get associativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

This is a very early stage exercise from J.B. Fraleigh, so it should be quite elementary, but I can't find a way to complete the Cayley table below in order for $*$ to be associative. I have googled the subject and found Light's method, but it's quite expensive in terms of computation, although not as much as writing down all possibilities. I wonder if there's some way to deduce the missing entries for this particular $*$ by writing down some conditions.

For example, I have the this feeling that this last line could be filled with $d$'s or $c$'s, but I cannot prove it.

$$
\begin{array}{l | cccc}
* & a & b & c & d \\ \hline
a & a & b & c & d \\
b & b & a & c & d \\
c & c & d & c & d \\
d &   &   &   &   \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I often approach things like this as logic puzzles, rather than math problems. Often times, all you can really do at some points is to just guess an entry and see if it leads to a contradiction or a solution. (and if you get a solution, then try the other guesses if you need all solutions)

Comment: It turns out there's a complete solutions guide to this book out there, so I wonder if the right procedure is to give the answer myself, leave this question open or delete it.